# MySql Can't Connect from LAN

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have a client logging device on a RPi trying to connect to a MySQL server on another RPi (192.168.2.204) and failing:

> pi@RPi0w-Logger:~ $ sudo python  envirologremote.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "envirologremote.py", line 7, in 
> conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.2.204",user="jim",passwd="xxxxxxxxx",db="EnviroLogger")
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 81, in Connect
> return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in **init**
> super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.2.204' (111)")

I can connect to the server using PHPMySQL using the same creds, so the server is working and available.

I can connect to a server running locally on the client RPi.

I've been reading various articles on the subject. They seem to home in on a binding option, but they're all over the place on the location and name of the configuration file. I've made sure anywhere I could find a configuration file that it says "bind=0.0.0.0", but nothing changes, even after I reboot.

Here are the user privs:
[image]

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is PHPMySQL running on the same server as the mysql server or on the same server you try to connect from with python. You need to explicitely grant permissions to a user to connect from a remote host. So additinoally to `jim@localhost` you also need to grant permissions for `jim@remotehost`

Comment: Server is on IP address ....204, client is running on IP address ....203. Although 203 has a running MySQL server, it's not the server I'm connecting to. See updated question showing privs by user....(on ....204)

Comment: Privileges seem fine. Firewall allows to connect to port 3306 from a remotehost? Or maybe this helps https://serverfault.com/questions/171655/mysql-allow-both-remote-and-local-connections  TL;DR: disable `bind-address` and disable `skip-networking`

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'root_password';
```

mysql> flush privileges;

replace ‘%’ to the IP you want to grant access for!

u need to provide privileges hope this work

Comment: `root@%` is quite dangerous because it allows root access from everywhere. If possible, you should restrict remote access to known hosts

Comment: As you'll note above, I am NOT using "root" for that specific reason. The user I've chosen has INSERT, SELECT, etc. privs, but not GRANT or other "root-like" privs.

Answer (score 0):

After a dozen tries, I finally found a configuration file with the "bind=127.0.0.1" statement on the 204 instance of MySQL. I had to learn some Linux Bash (grep....) to find it, but I found it in the MariaDB configuration file.

Thanks, I can now get the job done. I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and for me it ended up being an issue with the Windows Firewall.

I just opened up the advanced firewall settings, and made a new entry to allow any inbound connection on the port 3306, then I was able to connect using the LAN ip